# OnClick is not working on 2nd runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I have 2 List and a Datagridview. 1st List is for level and categories
 eg. Lvl1 - Cat1 , Lvl2 - Cat2

2nd list.

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="tabsss" OnClick="tabsss_Click" runat="server">SSS
     </asp:LinkButton></li>
    <li>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="tabphl" OnClick="tabphl_Click2" runat="server">Phil Health
     </asp:LinkButton></li>
    <li>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="tabhdmf" OnClick="tabhdmf_Click1" runat="server">HMDF
     </asp:LinkButton></li>
    <li>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="tabtax"  OnClick="tabtax_Click1" runat="server">TAX
     </asp:LinkButton></li>
</ul>
```

When I selected the 1st pair of Level and category, SqlDataSource works fine. When I clicked the 2nd pair, onclick (tabsss_Click & others) is not executing.

SQL DataSource

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MISConnectionString %>" 
             SelectCommandType ="StoredProcedure"
             SelectCommand="sp_SSSTable"
             UpdateCommand="UPDATE tbl_HRMS_SSSTable SET r_frm = @r_frm, r_to = @r_to, monthly = @monthly, ee_contrib = @ee_contrib, er_contrib = @er_contrib, ec_er_contrib = @ec_er_contrib WHERE (ID = @ID)">
      <SelectParameters>                                                               
      <asp:Parameter Name="EMPLVL" Type="String" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="EMPCAT" Type="String" />
      </SelectParameters>
      <UpdateParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="r_frm" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="r_to" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="monthly" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="ee_contrib" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="er_contrib" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="ec_er_contrib" />
      <asp:SessionParameter Name="ID" SessionField="empID" />
      </UpdateParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C#

```
protected void tabsss_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Panelsss.Visible = true;
        Panelhdmf.Visible = false;
        Paneltax.Visible = false;
        Panelphil.Visible = false;

        SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["EMPLVL"].DefaultValue = hdnEmplvl.Value;
        SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["EMPCAT"].DefaultValue = hdnEmpcat.Value;
        SqlDataSource2.DataBind();

        string script66 = "alertify.success('success');";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script66, true);
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in the method, does it receive the call?

Comment: Check out whether you've registered your events correctly or not. Like @shinjidev suggested, put a breakpoint at every event handlers and the click the buttons on your `2nd pair`.